# Text inside <div> tags - semantically correct or not?

Tags: html, text, browser, compatibility

Most of us have seen before something like this:

```
<div class="rights">All rights reserved!</div>
```

I just wanted to know, is this a right job? or althogh it will render in browser, it is better to use `<p>` tag for example?
I am asking this to know if it has any Google(SEO), Page load time, Compatibality, HTML Validity, ... issues/downsides.

Comment: The question is too broad and unspecific, but it is also primarily opinion-based. The theoretical difference between `div` and `p` in a simple case like this is that `div` has *no* semantics whereas `p` has the vague and abstract and debated “semantics” that is a paragraph, which is not really defined in any HTML spec or draft.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well first of all, most browsers will automatically add space (margin) around the `<p>` tag.

There is no real performance issue wether you use or not the `<p>` tag. Also, the html won't be invalid.

The main reason of using this tag would be to indicate to the browser that you are defining a block element.

Search engine optimization won't be affected by this.

**Edit** : In your example, you would be better using the `<p>` tag since the `<div>` is also a block element and has nothing else then text in it so it would be more specific.

Answer (score 5):

From [W3.org The div element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-div-element)

Authors are strongly encouraged to view the div element as an element of **last resort**, for when no other element is suitable. Use of more appropriate elements instead of the div element leads to better accessibility for readers and easier maintainability for authors.

As for validity etc, see answer by panther

Comment: Similar warning in WHATWG's Living Standard https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-div-element which is generally more authoritative

Answer (score 4):

It is safer to use `<p>` .Crawlers even prioritize bigger texts like `<h1>` and `<h2>` tags.

I've heard that crawlers also check the CSS formatting (in case you want to cheat with hidden texts with keywords), so this is a factor as well.

As for validity and performance, it does not matter.

Comment: The priority of Hx elements was higher in past, but yes, the headline is still more important than texts in paragraphs. But I don´t know what you meant here by this note. We spoke about div/p, not about headlines.

Answer (score 1):

It should be a paragraph, but it the string you don´t need semantically at all (people won´t searh this strin gto find out your website).

ad. **page load time** - no, it doesn´t matter if you use  or

ad. **compatibility** - paragraph has a margin, eg. when you disabled styles. Nothing else.

ad. **validity** - both is HTML valid, but validity has no effect to SEO. Doesn´t matter.